# Hystrix runtime configuration with Spring-Cloud-Config instead of Archaius?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix, hystrix

I'm studying Spring-Cloud-Netflix and I learned that Archaius was used for Hystrix runtime configuration. (https://ahus1.github.io/hystrix-examples/manual.html#archaius)

I also found that Archaius was a soft-dependency since V1.5.0 (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/pull/1083): "Archaius is now a soft-dependency of Hystrix, so you can supply your own configuration mechanism."

My question is, is it easy to configure Hystrix with Spring-Cloud-Config at runtime? I did some research but haven't found any examples.

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After several days' research, I managed to dynamically configure Hystrix properties with Spring Cloud Config. I also made a small demo on configuring the Hystrix instance property at runtime.

First, [each Hystrix property has four levels of precendence](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#introduction):

1. Global default
2. Dynamic global default
3. Instance default
4. Dynamic instance property.

Where the 1st and 3rd levels only support static configurations. Since the 2nd level (*dynamic global default*) was not discussed a lot in the Hystrix Wiki, I choose the *Dynamic Instance Property* for runtime configuration. However, I believe my method should apply to *Dynamic Global Default* as well.

The practice is simple. First pull a config value from Spring Cloud Config using the @Value annotation:

```
@Value("{timeoutInMilliseconds:1500}")
String timeout;
```

Then use the string `timeout` in your Hystrix instance:

```
ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty("hystrix.command.HystrixHelloWorld.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", timeout);
```

Where the `ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance()` is an [Archaius method](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/blob/master/archaius-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/config/ConfigurationManager.java), returns a configuration instance. `.setProperty()` sets the property